# Fill facebook share item with title, text and link (Android)

Tags: android, facebook, share

I am trying to post a link on facebook with the native android sharing function. I found out that i can't set the message for the link. But now i want to set the title, message and the url.

[image]

I want to set the items in the red square. I already found out I couldnt set the Test, because of the user policies.

Some code:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();

shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, title);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, title + "\n\n" + contentLink);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");

return shareIntent;
```

This is the code I have at this moment, but this doesnt set the items in the red square.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Text Sharing :**
Using Android Intent Share for Facebook you can't share pre-populated text. This is blocked by facebook itself due to platform policy. Checkout section 2.3 in the below linl

https://developers.facebook.com/policy

**Link Sharing :**
You can share a link. Facebook will automatically fetch the link metadata. i.e a image, meta title and meta description.

**Image Sharing :** 
User images can be shared. Which means you can share images stored on your device. You cannot share images from your app directly without saving them. As a hack, you can save the image on device, share and delete the image (if you don't want image to appear in user's gallery).

Comment: About the text sharing, you mean the section TEST right? or is the information inside the red square also seen as pre-populated text?

Comment: Ooh nevermind, the text inside the red box should be in the meta data of the website right? with link sharing?

Comment: yes.. that should be metadata fetched from website.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code to share only link. Facebook will automatically fetch the link metadata. i.e, image, meta title and meta description.

```
String urlToShare = "--------URL-------";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, urlToShare);

// See if official Facebook app is found
boolean facebookAppFound = false;
List<ResolveInfo> matches = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
for (ResolveInfo info : matches) 
{
 if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().startsWith("com.facebook")) 
 {
  intent.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                    facebookAppFound = true;
                    break;
 }
}


if (!facebookAppFound) 
{
 String sharerUrl = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=" + urlToShare;
 intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(sharerUrl));
}
startActivity(intent);
```